# AngularJS Dynamic head data conventions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, metadata, head

I'm creating a new AngularJS 1.x application (which i'm fairly new to) and am not familiar with conventions of updating dynamically updating head data, currently I'm using a service to update every page as so. But this is going to be a sizable project and It already seems redundant repeating this a dozen times with dozens more to come. What conventions would anyone recommend for this if there's an alternative to applying a service to every page controller?

This is a snippet of the code I'll have to apply to every controller:

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

 angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('MainController', MainController);

 function MainController(MetadataService) {  
   MetadataService.setMetaTags({
     title: 'Main',
     description: 'This is a description of the main page'
   });
 }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware. You could however add your service to the `angular` object and call it from there in your controllers.

So it would look something like this:

```
angular
   .module('app').run(['MetadataService', function(MetadataService) {
       angular.MetadataService = MetadataService;
    }])
```

Now in your controller you should be able to do:

`angular.MetadataService`

without explicitly injecting the service.

Comment: It does work but I'm not really sure if editing the angular object would be the best thing to do? But regardless it does the job thanks!